# Mysql Change position of rows to columns from repeated data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I need to change the rows from repeated ids to columns.
The example will explain better my problem

What I have:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | id_data   | values|
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |    1      | data1 |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  2 |    1      | data2 |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  3 |    1      | data3 |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  4 |    2      | data4 |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  5 |    2      | data5 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

What I want:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | id_data | option1 | option2 | option3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | data1   | data2   | data3   |
|  2 |       2 | data4   | data5   | 0       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Instead, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation. The following code will work correctly only if the `id` grows sequentially by one.

```
select t.id_data,
       max(case when cn = 0 then values end) as option1,
       max(case when cn = 1 then values end) as option2,
       max(case when cn = 2 then values end) as option3
from
(
    select *, 
           id - (select min(id) from data d2 where d1.id_data = d2.id_data) cn
    from data d1
) t
group by t.id_data
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=25987c6e25cebc30f42ae30887b8b551)

if there are 'gaps' in the `id` values then the `cn` can be computed using a self join.